# Play Framework Bean Validation of Primitive Types

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, bean-validation

I am using the following class to validate a form submission as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/JavaForms

```java
public class ExampleForm {
    @Required
    public int height;
    public String payload;
}
```

When I perform the bindFromRequest() the @Required constraint is ignored. However, it works when I change the primitive type to the boxed type:

```java
public class ExampleForm {
    @Required
    public Integer height;
    public String payload;
}
```

Is the bean validation not working with primitive types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation is easy: databases allows NULL values, and primitive types doesn't. As the Form is de facto some kind of connector between UI and DB model it expects objects instead of primitives.

`@Required` checks if `object` is null in first step and int is NOT null.

Keep as a rule to use `Integer` instead of `int` in both - models and forms and you'll your validators will always work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. That does make sense. Just one remark: My model is not bound to a database. It's just a helper model to easily validate the form input. So I haven't thought about the database.

Comment: Anyway I just assume that Play's creators didn't want to include two different ways for doing the same thing ;)